# Can't Install Pyaudio

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Can't install Pyaudio in my python 3.7..even tried installing visual c++.

```
pip install pyaudio
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyaudio
  Complete output from command "c:\users\vicky kumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe" -c "import setuptools;__file__='C:\\Users\\VICKYK~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-5v23nswh\\pyaudio\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\VICKYK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmprsn0men8pip-wheel-:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio
    Complete output from command "c:\users\vicky kumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe" -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\VICKYK~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-5v23nswh\\pyaudio\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\VICKYK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-m53gsf79-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\users\vicky kumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe" -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\VICKYK~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-5v23nswh\\pyaudio\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\VICKYK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-m53gsf79-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\VICKYK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-5v23nswh\pyaudio
```

Comment: Please Help Me out.

Comment: The error messages seem to indicate you don't have `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0` installed. You may be able to download and use the pre-built module at Christoph Gohke's [Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio) download page.

Comment: I am getting this error even though I have Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 installed.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you cant install Pyaudio is your python version, the last version of python that support Pyaudio is python 3.6
So you have to install python 3.6 or 3.5 or 3.4 or python 2.7.
after installing python 3.6 use this link and download pyaudio.whl according to your os. 
then use this command to install it:

```
pip install <package_name>.whl
```

Answer (score 1):

To install the latest version of pyaudio using conda:

```
source activate -your environment name-
pip install pyaudio
```

If you encounter PortAudio development package error, install it with

```
sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev
```